# Only last line of the Exception stack trace shows up

Tags: c#, exception, .net-2.0, unhandled-exception

I am having some trouble collecting information on an unhandled exception being generated (very rarely) in my code. I have set up an the handler pretty much the standard way.

In the main I have:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(ExceptionProcessor);
```

And the handler function is:

```
public void ExceptionProcessor(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    Log(((Exception)e.ExceptionObject).StackTrace);
}
```

But all I ever get is a single line (not always the same one). Googling revealed that those lines are deep inside the .Net Framework libraries and are meant to be the very last line of the stack trace. So, all of the actually useful information about my code is missing. Does anyone know what could be causing this behaviour?

The line I got most recently says that it can't cast System.Threading.AutoResetEvent to System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm probably asking the obvious, but is there an InnerException?

Comment: Are you compiling to Debug or Release mode?  It's possible that the compiler could be inlining some of your functions.  You also lose line numbers in your stack trace.

Comment: @Dave I do lose line numbers with release, but when I catch normal exceptions I don't loose any stack trace, this behaviour is unique to the UnhandledException case.

Comment: @Steve, if it was the inner exception, then shouldn't the deep .Net exception be the inner one? At any rate, I will make the modifications, it's still a good suggestion to collect all the stack trace recursively though the inner exceptions. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post actual exception and stack trace you receive?

Comment: @Nick, original question updated.

Comment: @United, but where? I want to check system assemblys in case of something specific there. Also dump e.ExceptionObject.ToString() and post here please. Can you show what exact it contains?

Comment: @United, if it not helps, you can go for WinDbg/AdPlus or manual creating minidump file and debug it to see what exactly happens there

Comment: the issue is extremely rare, but very disruptive... might be weeks before it happens again, I will follow up when it does (I've put new instrumentation in place to gather info). I hope I'll be able to revive this after all that time. Right now, all the information I have is already in the OP.

Comment: @United, so better start with capturing dump to investigate it. It will contains full enough info for debug.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite strange.  What is the type of e.ExceptionObject?  Is it a custom exception?

My bet is that there's some situation occurring where your actual exception of interest is being caught and then re-thrown somewhere...

Comment: The type is InvalidCastException (default .Net one). And I had the same thought about re-throw :) I've tested it out and re-throwing looses the deep levels while creating the new stack top (at my code level). What I'm see is the opposite, only the deepest level is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes use e.tostring() to write the whole exception details into the log. try that..

Answer (score 0):

Do you log inner exceptions? Each exception has `InnerException` property which may contain another exception.